# How to ensure that class derived from abstract generic class uses itself as generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : MyAbstractBase<T> {}
```

where I derive a couple of classes:

```
public class Concrete1 : MyAbstractBase<Concrete1> {};
public class Concrete2 : MyAbstractBase<Concrete2> {};
```

is there a way to constraint MyAbstractBase so that the the generic type is that of the specific concrete type?

So this should produce a compiler error:

```
public class Concrete1 : MyAbstractBase<Concrete2> {};
```

My current workaround is a check in the base constructor which doesn't throw a compiler warning unfortunately.

```
protected MyAbstractBase()
{
    _ = this as T ?? throw new Exception("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

This article lists all the available constraints for generic type parameters. Unfortunately, there seems to be no constraint that does what you need.